# I need help please

Tags: plotting, physics

Can Anyone help I did this to get the same graph but

[image]

```
c = 2.998 10^8;
h = 6.62607015 10^-34;
Kb = 1.380649 10^-23;


i[\[Lambda]_,
   T_] := ((2 Pi h c^2)/(\[Lambda]^5 (Exp[(h c)/(\[Lambda] Kb T)] -
      1)));


M = Plot[i[\[Lambda], 3000], {\[Lambda], 0, 2.5 10^-6},
   PlotRange -> Automatic,
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness [0.005], Green},
   Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Green ];

N = [i[\[Lambda], 4000], {\[Lambda], 0, 2.5 10^-6},
   PlotRange -> Automatic ,
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness [0.005], Blue, Dashed},
    Filling -> Axis];

O =  [i[\[Lambda], 5000], {\[Lambda], 0, 2.5 10^-6},
   PlotRange -> Automatic ,
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness [0.005], Orange}];

Show[M , N , O, GridLines -> Automatic , PlotRange -> Automatic ,
  Frame -> True , AxesLabel -> {\[Lambda][m], (watts/m^3)},
  Epilog -> {Insert [
     Framed[Style["T=3000K", 10], Background -> White], {8.23 10^-7,
      5.42 10^13}],
    Insert [
     Framed[Style["T=4000K", 10], Background -> White], {8.23 10^-7,
      1.64 10^13}],
    Insert [
     Framed[Style["T=5000K", 10], Background -> White], {8.75 10^-7,
      3.90 10^13}]}] // Quiet
```

and I get this "is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision 
may be lost". Can anyone help please

Comment: @MichaelE2 -- As the duplicate also got deleted, shouldn't this one stand.  The OP did put in some effort.  He clearly researched using `Epilog` and `Show`.  The OP certainly made some simple errors, but they tried something, which goes beyond what the site gets from lots of 1st time posters.

Comment: @Jagra I don't know what you mean: The duplicate is there. It's almost word-for-word exactly they same. I thought the community frowned strongly on people posting the same question over and over again. (Seems reasonable to me.  Your answer should be added to it.)